# How to deal with that kind of json?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

The backend returns this kind of json:

***UPDATED: 2018-12-27***

```
{
  "3dfb71719a11693760f91f26f4f79c3c": {
    "a-type": {
      "var1": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
      "var2": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      }
    },
    "b-type": {
      "var3": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
    },
    "c-type": {
      "var4": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
    }
  },
  "c91891522a8016fc8a097b9e405b118a": {
    "a-type": {
      "var1": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
      "var2": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
    },
    "b-type": {
      "var3": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
    },
    "c-type": {
      "var4": {
        "value": "8678468,4,2,2,0,0",
        "time": 1544536734000
      },
    }
  }
}
```

The first parameter, is a unique key. I wanted to take some inspiration from this nice blog from Poojã Bhaumik (https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51), but not sure how to deal with the above json. In fact, is more about the first unique key that I don't know how to deal with it.

Another thing. I would like to use 'flutter packages pub run build_runner build' command to generate the .g.dart file like explained [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#creating-model-classes-the-json_serializable-way)

Would you mind to give me some hint?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with that kind of json"?

Comment: loop over the root items. You don't have to know the key for a node to handle it - if you need to handle them all. In what way do you need to 'deal with that kind of json'?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand clear, your problem is that the keys from that map will be randomly unique ID’s.

You can pick your `keySet` and then loop for each key to create each object and it’s own nested objects. Something like this:

```
void main(){

  Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode('yourBodyResponse');
  List<MyObject> myObjects = List<MyObject>();

  final keys = map.keys;

  keys.forEach((id){
    final MyObject obj = MyObject.fromJson(id, map[id]); 
    myObjects.add(obj);
  });

}

class ABC {

  final String value;
  final int time;

  ABC({this.value, this.time});

}

class Def { 

  final String value;
  final int time;

  Def({this.value, this.time});

}

class MyObject {

  final String id;
  final ABC abc;
  final Def def;

  MyObject({this.id,
            this.abc,
            this.def
           });


factory MyObject.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return MyObject(
      id: id,
      abc: ABC(
        value: json['abc']['value'],
        time: json['abc']['time']),
      def: Def(
        value: json['def']['value'], 
        time: json['def']['time']),
    );
}

}
```

Disclaimer: I’ve created the code on my phone with DartPad, although it should be fine, might not be well formated, miss a bracket or have a typo.

Comment: Hi @miguelpruivo. Would you mind to look out the update json data and let me know of what you would change? Thanks

Comment: Is this a real json example of what you get? Because if so, you'll have a few objects.  It's multiple nested maps.